# What is the correct way to edit table widths in woo commerce one page checkout?

Tags: css, woocommerce

The product quantity column is much too long by default. here.

I have tried the following in "customize CSS" on wordpress (Theme: Twenty-Twenty)

```
.td class=product-quanity { 
    width:20%; 
}

table.product-quanity td {
    width:20%;
}

table td.product-quanity {
    width:20%;
}
```

I am sure I am missing some form of context. Thanks.

Comment: just a quick check - is that class meant to be "product-quantity"?

Comment: Good gravy...LOL. Thanks. That even helped solve the other.

Comment: No worries, I have made that comment into an answer so it can be accepted to close this out.

Answer (score 0):

Is that class meant to be "product-quantity"?